# Node Promises and returning values

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, blocking

I have been struggling to shore up my understanding of JavaScript's promises and asynchronicity. I understand that the sample below will not work as expected and that "someStuff" will return an empty array. I also believe that I understand that this is because "doPromise" does not block, so the loop completes and returns an empty array before "doPromise" has ever resolved.

What I do not understand is how I can accomplish this same functionality expressed in this example, the appropriate way.

I suppose my question is: what's the "right" way to do this? Thanks in advance!

```
function doPromise(number){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        resolve(number + 10);
    });
}

function someStuff(){
    var values = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 10;i++){
        doPromise(i).then((sum)=>{
            values.push(sum);
        });
    }
    return values;
}

console.log(someStuff());
```

Comment: because `someStuff` uses Promises, it can not return the result synchronously. You'll need to return a promise that resolves once all those promises are resolved ... this is what Promise.all is good for ... `values.push(doPromise(i))` in the loop, and `return Promise.all(values)` - of course, you'll have to change the calling code as well ... `someStuff().then(result => console.log(result))` - or just `someStuff().then(console.log)`

Comment: Don't use `number` as a parameter/variable name. It's a reserved word in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "doPromise" does not block, so the loop completes and returns an empty array before any "doPromise()" has ever resolved.

Yes. This also means that you *cannot* return an array of results synchronously, you can only get the values after all promises have resolved. So your `someStuff` function is asynchronous as well, and so it should return a promise (for the array of results).

To get a promise for an array of results from an array of promises, you can use the [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) function.

```
function someStuff() {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        promises.push(doPromise(i));
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

someStuff().then(values => {
    console.log(values);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `async await`

```
function doPromise(number) {
    return new Promise(( resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(number + 10);
    });
}


async function someStuff() {
    var values = [];

    for ( var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) {
        const sum = await doPromise(i).catch(ex => console.log("error: ", ex));
        values.push(sum);
    }
    return values;
}

someStuff().then( val => {
    console.log(val);
});
```

You should note that returning from an async function without using `.then` on the async function call with only show you an unresolved promise ( pending ). To be able to do this without using `.then` you have to wait for few months until `TC39` standardizes toplevel await

Comment: Your `.catch()` handler is going to push an `undefined` value into the array.  Is that really what you want?